Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'IServiceProvider' in MassTransit
I got Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'IServiceProvider' in MassTransit on server, but have no problems on local machine.
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at MassTransit.Configuration.RegistrationContext.GetService(Type serviceType) in /_/src/MassTransit/DependencyInjection/Configuration/RegistrationContext.cs:line 133
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.CreateScope(IServiceProvider provider)
   at MassTransit.DependencyInjection.BaseConsumeScopeProvider.GetScopeContext[TScopeContext,TPipeContext](TPipeContext context, Func`4 existingScopeContextFactory, Func`4 createdScopeContextFactory, Func`4 pipeContextFactory) in /_/src/MassTransit/DependencyInjection/DependencyInjection/BaseConsumeScopeProvider.cs:line 40
   at MassTransit.DependencyInjection.ConsumeScopeProvider.GetScope[TConsumer,T](ConsumeContext`1 context) in /_/src/MassTransit/DependencyInjection/DependencyInjection/ConsumeScopeProvider.cs:line 43
   at MassTransit.DependencyInjection.ScopeConsumerFactory`1.Send[TMessage](ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/DependencyInjection/DependencyInjection/ScopeConsumerFactory.cs:line 20
   at MassTransit.Middleware.ConsumerMessageFilter`2.MassTransit.IFilter<MassTransit.ConsumeContext<TMessage>>.Send(ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/ConsumerMessageFilter.cs:line 48
   at MassTransit.Middleware.ConsumerMessageFilter`2.MassTransit.IFilter<MassTransit.ConsumeContext<TMessage>>.Send(ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/ConsumerMessageFilter.cs:line 73
   at MassTransit.Middleware.TransactionFilter`1.Send(T context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/TransactionFilter.cs:line 48
   at MassTransit.Middleware.RetryFilter`1.MassTransit.IFilter<TContext>.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/RetryFilter.cs:line 47

First it started with my custom Dapper repo. But now I copied code from DapperIntegration lib and changed sql methods only.
My setup for MT:
public static void ConfigureMassTransit(IServiceCollection services, RabbitMqConfiguration rabbitConfig, RabbitMqQueueConfiguration queueConfig, string sagaConnectionString)
{
    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        x.AddConsumers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        var entryAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();

        x.AddSagaStateMachine<CaseSagaStateMachine, CaseSagaState>()                
        .DapperRepository(sagaConnectionString)
        .Endpoint(e =>
        {
            e.Name = queueConfig.CaseServiceBus;
        });
        
        x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
        {

            cfg.Host(new Uri($"rabbitmq://{rabbitConfig.Host}/{rabbitConfig.VirtualHost}"), host =>
            {
                host.Username(rabbitConfig.UserName);
                host.Password(rabbitConfig.Password);
            });

            
            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(queueConfig.CaseServiceBus, endPoint => //replace with our created queue
            {
                endPoint.UseMessageRetry(retry =>
                {
                    retry.Intervals(new[] { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 }.Select(t => TimeSpan.FromMinutes(t)).ToArray());
                });

                endPoint.UseTransaction(x =>
                {
                    x.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90);
                    x.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
                });

                //endPoint.UseInlineFilter(async (context, next) =>
                //{
                //    var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions
                //    {
                //        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
                //        IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted,
                //    };


                //    using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, transactionOptions, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
                //    {
                //        await next.Send(context).ConfigureAwait(false);
                //        scope.Complete();
                //    }
                //});
                endPoint.ConfigureSagas(context);
                endPoint.ConfigureConsumers(context);
            });

            cfg.PrefetchCount =  10;
        });
    });

    services.Configure<MassTransitHostOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.WaitUntilStarted = true;
        options.StartTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        options.StopTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    });
   
    services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, BusService>();

}

Commented sections are just for test.
Reworked code and I'm using DapperIntegration lib. But error still there

Why would you expect to be able to access a disposed object?  Why would you want to?

Maybe you've used a using  declaration/statement on the service provider somewhere?

@roten I do not use IServiceProvider anywhere in project. At least not manually

@ScottHunter I did not expect anything. Per StackTrace error was raised from lib and I have no access to it

@romandemidov Did you follow this guide to integrate with MassTransit?

@roten updated question. Yes I used just a standard way for it.

@romandemidov I don't think it's the issue, but just to point out - you should be using AddHostedService<T>() method to register your hosted services. Unfortunately I don't see any other issues in the code you've posted.

@roten yes I tried AddHostedService too
